# eth0 (modem usb) and wlan0 (wifi module) interconnection

Tags: linux, networking, routes, bridge, hostapd

I'm trying to either make a bridge between eth0 (Usb modem) and wlan0 (Wifi Hotspot) or route all traffic from wlan0 to eth0.

Procedure:

Bridge won't be successful if the interfaces already have an ip.

```
ip addr flush dev eth0
ip addr flush dev wlan0
```

Create the bridge and add the network.

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0
```

Start the wifi hotspot. At this point I can see the network with my phone.

```
hostapd /etc/hostapd.conf -B &
```

Assign the bridge an ip.

```
ifconfig br0 192.168.0.1
```

Start dhcp-server so my hotspot can automatically assign an ip address to the connected devices.

```
/etc/init.d/S80dhcp-server start
```

Reset my bridge.

```
ifdown br0
ifup br0
```

Configuration files

hostapd.conf:

```
interface=wlan0 
bridge=br0 
driver=nl80211 
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd 
ssid=My_Network 
dtim_period=2 
beacon_int=100 
channel=7 
hw_mode=g 
max_num_sta=8 
ap_max_inactivity=300
```

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet manual
bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
```

/etc/dhcp/dhcp.conf

```
ddns-update-style none;
option domain-name "google.com";
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.0.100 192.168.0.110;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
  option routers 192.168.0.1;
}
```

The dhcp-server returned OK but when I try to connect to the wifi hotspot I can't get an ip.
Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it done. 
I didn't use bridge but iptables.

Just these two commands were enough:

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 192.168.0.1/24 -j MASQUERADE

[Here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15300/bridge-eth0-static-wlan0-static-wlan1-dhcp) is the source of the answer with the explanation